# OpenGl - Object inverts after 180 degrees of rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I have an object rendered and I'm trying to rotate the object with the mouse. The object will rotate fine for 180 degrees but after that, the object inverts (if facing toward camera, switches to face away from camera) as does the expected movement of the mouse i.e. if dragging the mouse to the right rotates the object clockwise, then it will now rotate anti-clockwise. Once it reaches the next 180 degrees, it inverts again and normality is restored. I'm sure there must be something simple that I'm just not seeing?

Here is my code:

```
// Detect mouse state
void
mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        moving = 1;
        beginX = x;
        beginY = y;
    }
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        moving = 0;
    }
}

// Detect mouse movement
void motion(int x, int y)
{
    if (moving)
    {
        angleX = (angleX + (x - beginX));
        angleY = (angleY + (y - beginY));
        beginX = x;
        beginY = y;
        newModel = 1;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

// Rotate object
void recalcModelView(void)
{
    // Get object's centre
    int hh = head->GetHeight() / 2;
    int hw = head->GetWidth() / 2;
    int hd = head->GetDepth() / 2;
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    // Rotate object based on mouse movement
    glTranslatef(hw, hd, hh);
    float temp1 = angleX / 5;
    float temp2 = angleY / 5;
    printf("TEMP1: %g\n", temp1);
    printf("TEMP2: %g\n", temp2);
    glRotatef(temp1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(-temp2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(-hw, -hd, -hh);
    newModel = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "inverts as does the expected movement of it"? Your code looks fine, I think.

Comment: I'm not an OpenGL expert, but your use of `glPopMatrix(); glPushMatrix();` sequence is suspicious.

Comment: @Xymostech Apologies. That was a typo. Meant the mouse movement inverts as well i.e. if dragging the mouse to the right normally the object rotates clockwise, then dragging the mouse to the right will now make the object rotate anti-clockwise

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [Arcball](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Arcball) to fix this.